# usos y funcion del List<String> en JSP

Tags: java, jsp

amigos tengo una vista que actualmente mediante una consulta con dos parametros me muestra un resultado, el problema es que me muestra solo un resultado en la tabla, actualmente recibo los parametros y mando la respuesta usando object map, de la siguiente manera

```
@RequestMapping("/ajax_consultaProducto")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                  @RequestParam("buscarProductoInput") String codigoBarra,
                                  @RequestParam("comboboxSucursales") String sucursal,
                                  @RequestParam("IpCC") String ipControlador
) throws Exception {
    logger.info("LLamado a metodos consultaProducto y buscarEstatusProducto Parametros: " + em + ", " + codigoBarra + ", " + sucursal);
    int mensajeEnviar;
    codigoBarra = codigoBarra.replace(" ", "");
    IConsultaProductosRms consultaRms = new ConsultaProductosRms();
    Producto producto = null;
    Map<Integer, Object> mapRetorno = null;
    producto = consultaRms.consultaProducto(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
    mensajeEnviar = consultaRms.buscarEstatusProducto(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
    producto.setStatusProducto(Integer.toString(mensajeEnviar));
    mapRetorno = transformObjectToTreeMap(producto);
    logger.info("Producto devuelto transformado en map:  " + mapRetorno);
    return new ModelAndView("ajax_sucursales", "lista", mapRetorno);
}
```

pero no se si debido a esta forma es que me muestra un solo registro en la vista, estaba pensando en hace uso de List para ver si lo muestra en forma de lista, algo asi:

```
@RequestMapping("/tabla_consultaProductos")
    public ModelAndView consultaProductos(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                  @RequestParam("buscarProductoInput") String codigoBarra,
                                                  @RequestParam("comboboxSucursales") String sucursal,
                                                  @RequestParam("IpCC") String ipControlador
    ) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Antes de la ejecutar consultaProducto" + codigoBarra + ", " + sucursal + ", "
                + ipControlador);
        codigoBarra = codigoBarra.replace(" ", "");
        IConsultaProductosRms consultaRms = new ConsultaProductosRms();

        List<String> listaBarra = consultaRms.consultaProductos(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);

        logger.info("Despu\u00E9s de la ejecutar consultaProductoPromocion retorna: "+ listaBarra);
        return new ModelAndView("tabla_consultaProductos", "lista", listaBarra);
    }
```

sera que de esta manera puede funcionar? acepto sugerencias gracias

aca hago el llamado a el metodo que realiza el query

```
public interface IConsultaProductosRms {
    @Transactional
        public List<String> consultarProductosPromocionInactivos(EntityManager em, String codigoPromocion,String sucursal);

    public Producto consultaProducto(EntityManager em,String codigoBarra, String sucursal);

        public List<String> consultaProductos(EntityManager em,String codigoBarra, String sucursal);
    public Mensaje actualizaProductoSistemas(DriverManagerDataSource em, String codigoPrincipal, int numeroSucursal);
    public List<String> consultaBarrasSecundarias(EntityManager em, String codigoBarra,String sucursal);
    public List<String> consultaProductosPromocion(EntityManager em, String codigoPromocion,String sucursal);
        public int buscarEstatusProducto(EntityManager em, String codigoBarra, String sucursal);
}
```

esta en particular es la que uso

```
public Producto consultaProducto(EntityManager em,String codigoBarra, String sucursal);
```

aca esta el metodo consultaProducto

```
public Producto consultaProducto(EntityManager em, String codigoBarra,
            String sucursal) {


/*Query original en actual funcionamiento
        String stringQuery = "SELECT * " + "FROM ( "
        + "SELECT tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal, "
        + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionCorta, "
        + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionLarga, " + "im.dept, "
        + "vi.vat_rate, " + "rfr2.selling_retail, "
        + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_start_date,'yyyymmdd'), " + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_end_date,'yyyymmdd'), "
        + "rpile.promo_comp_id, " + "rpile.promo_id, "
        + "DECODE(uil.uda_value, " + "'0', " + "'Normal', " + "'4', "
        + "'Pesable', " + "'7', " + "'Procesado') estado, "
        + "rfr2.simple_promo_retail,null,im.standard_uom,MFG_REC_RETAIL  " + "FROM item_master       im, "
        + "vat_item          vi, " + "store             s, "
        + "uda_item_lov      uil, " + "rpm_future_retail rfr2, " +

        "(SELECT decode(im.item_number_type, " + "'ITEM', "
        + "im.item, " + "im.item_parent) codigoPrincipal, "
        + "im.item_desc descripcionLarga, "
        + "im.short_desc descripcionCorta " + "FROM item_master im "
        + "WHERE im.item = ?1) tmp_barra_primaria " +

        "LEFT OUTER JOIN(item_loc il) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = il.item AND "
        + "il.loc = ?2) " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_future_retail rfr) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rfr.item AND "
        + "rfr.location = ?2 AND "
        + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= "
        + "TO_DATE(rfr.action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
        + "(to_date(sysdate) - to_date(rfr.action_date)) >= 0) "
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rpile.item AND "
        + "rpile.location = ?2 AND "
        + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between "
        + "TO_DATE(rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
        + "to_date(rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) " +

        "WHERE im.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
        + "AND vi.item = im.item " + "AND s.store = ?2 "
        + "AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region "
        + "AND uil.item = im.item " + "AND uil.uda_id = 3 "
        + "AND rfr2.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
        + "AND rfr2.location = ?2 " +

        "AND (to_date(SYSDATE) - to_date(rfr2.action_date)) >= 0 "
        + "   ORDER BY rfr2.action_date DESC ,vi.active_date DESC  " +

        ") tempo " + "WHERE ROWNUM = 1";*/

        String query2 = "SELECT   temp.codigoPrincipal,"
             +"temp.descripcionCorta,"
             +"temp.descripcionLarga,"
             +"im.dept,"
             +"vi.vat_rate,"
             +"rfr.selling_retail,"
             +"TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),"
             +"TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),"
             +"rpile.promo_comp_id,"
             +"rpile.promo_id,"
             +" DECODE (uil.uda_value,"
                +"     '0',"
                +"     'Normal',"
                +"     '4',"
                +"     'Pesable',"
                +"     '7',"
                +"     'Procesado')"
               +" estado,"
            +" rfr.simple_promo_retail,"
            +" NULL,"
            +" im.standard_uom,"
            +" im.MFG_REC_RETAIL,"
            +" s.store_name"
     +" FROM                        item_master im"
                            +"   JOIN"
                                 +" (SELECT   DECODE (im.item_number_type,"
                                               +"     'ITEM', im.item,"
                                                  +"  im.item_parent)"
                                             +"  codigoPrincipal,"
                                           +" im.item_desc descripcionLarga,"
                                          +"  im.short_desc descripcionCorta"
                                   +"  FROM   item_master im"
                                   +" WHERE   im.item = ?1) temp"
                             +"  ON (im.item = temp.codigoPrincipal)"
                           +" JOIN"
                            +"   uda_item_lov uil"
                           +" ON (im.item = uil.item AND uda_id = 3)"
                        +" LEFT JOIN"
                        +"   item_loc il"
                        +" ON (im.item = il.item)"
                      +" LEFT JOIN"
                      +"   rpm_future_retail rfr"
                      +" ON (rfr.item = il.item AND rfr.location = il.loc)"
                  +" LEFT JOIN"
                  +"    rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile"
                  +" ON (rfr.item = rpile.item AND rpile.location = rfr.location)"
                  +" AND TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE (rpile.detail_start_date,"
                  +" 'DD/MM/YYYY')AND  TO_DATE (rpile.detail_end_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')"
               +" JOIN"
                 +"  store s"
               +" ON (il.loc = s.store)"
            +" JOIN"
            +" vat_item vi"
            +" ON (im.item = vi.item AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region)"
     +"WHERE       store = DECODE (?2, '0', s.store, ?2)"
             +"AND (TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(rfr.action_date)) >= '0'"
             +"AND VI.VAT_TYPE IN ('R', 'B')"
             +"AND vi.active_date IN"
                    +"  (SELECT   MAX (active_date)"
                     +"    FROM   vat_item vi1"
                      +"  WHERE       vi.item = vi1.item"
                             +"   AND vi.vat_type = vi1.vat_type"
                              +"  AND vi1.create_date <= TRUNC (SYSDATE)"
                              +"  AND vi.vat_region = vi1.vat_region)";

        Producto productoRetornar = new Producto();
        List<Vector<Object>> objetos=new ArrayList();
        try
        {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(query2);
        query.setParameter(1, codigoBarra);
        query.setParameter(2, sucursal);
                //query.setParameter(3, sucursal);




         objetos = query.getResultList();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            productoRetornar.setMensaje("No se puede conectar"+e.getMessage());
        }
        for (Vector<Object> resultElement : objetos) {

            String codigoPrincipal = null;
            try {
                codigoPrincipal = resultElement.get(0).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String descripcionCorta = null;
            try {
                descripcionCorta = resultElement.get(1).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String descripcionLarga = null;
            try {
                descripcionLarga = resultElement.get(2).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String departamento = null;
            try {
                departamento = resultElement.get(3).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String iva = null;
            try {
                iva = resultElement.get(4).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String precio = null;
            try {
                precio = resultElement.get(5).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String fechaInicioPromocion = null;
            try {
                fechaInicioPromocion = resultElement.get(6).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String fechaFinPromocion = null;
            try {
                fechaFinPromocion = resultElement.get(7).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String codigoComponente = null;
            try {
                codigoComponente = resultElement.get(8).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String codigoPromocion = null;
            try {
                codigoPromocion = resultElement.get(9).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String estado = null;
            try {
                estado = resultElement.get(10).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String precioPromocion = null;
            try {
                if(codigoPromocion!= null)
                    precioPromocion = resultElement.get(11).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String frecuencia = null;
            try {
                frecuencia = resultElement.get(12).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String uom = null;
            try {
                uom = resultElement.get(13).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String pvJusto = null;
            try {
                pvJusto = resultElement.get(14).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
                        String nombreSucursal = null;
            try {
                nombreSucursal = resultElement.get(14).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if(!objetos.isEmpty())
            {
                productoRetornar.setCodigoPrincipal(codigoPrincipal);
                productoRetornar.setDescripcionCorta(descripcionCorta);
                productoRetornar.setDescripcionLarga(descripcionLarga);
                productoRetornar.setDepartamento(departamento);
                productoRetornar.setIva(iva);
                productoRetornar.setPrecio(precio); 
                productoRetornar.setFechaInicioPromocion(fechaInicioPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setFechaFinPromocion(fechaFinPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setCodigoComponente(codigoComponente);
                productoRetornar.setCodigoPromocion(codigoPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setEstado(estado);
                productoRetornar.setPrecioPromocion(precioPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setFrecuencia(frecuencia);
                productoRetornar.setUom(uom);
                productoRetornar.setMensaje("");
                productoRetornar.setPvJusto(pvJusto);
                                productoRetornar.setNombreSucursal(nombreSucursal);
            }
        }

        return productoRetornar;
    }
```

y aca es la vista en donde hago el llamado de ajax_consultaProducto

```
.post(
                        'ConsultasRms/ajax_consultaProducto.html',
                        formulario.serialize(),
                        function (data) {
                            $("#loading").hide();

                            //borramos el contenido de los option del select
                            //$("#comboboxSucursales").html("");
                            //recorremos todas las filas del resultado del proceso que obtenemos en Json


                            if (data.lista[1].codigoPrincipal == null) {
                                $("#dialog-NoData").dialog("open");
                            }


                            else if (data.lista[1].statusProducto == "1") {
                                $("#dialog-Inactivo").dialog("open");
                            }


                            else {
                                comboSucursales = document
                                        .getElementById('comboboxSucursales');
                                sucursalConsulta = comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].text;
                                if (data.lista[1].mensaje == "") {
                                    var datarow = {
                                        sucursal: sucursalConsulta,
                                        numeroSucursal: comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].value,
                                        ip: ipControlador,
                                        sistema: tipoSucursal,
                                        codigoPrincipal: data.lista[1].codigoPrincipal,
                                        descripcionCorta: data.lista[1].descripcionCorta,
                                        precio: data.lista[1].precio,
                                        precioPromocion: data.lista[1].precioPromocion,
                                        pvJusto: data.lista[1].pvJusto,
                                        nombreSucursal: data.lista[1].nombreSucursal
                                    };
                                    datarowRmsDetalle[cont] = {
                                        descripcionLarga: data.lista[1].descripcionLarga,
                                        iva: data.lista[1].iva,
                                        estado: data.lista[1].estado,
                                        departamento: data.lista[1].departamento,
                                        codigoComponente: data.lista[1].codigoComponente,
                                        codigoPromocion: data.lista[1].codigoPromocion,
                                        fechaInicioPromocion: data.lista[1].fechaInicioPromocion,
                                        fechaFinPromocion: data.lista[1].fechaFinPromocion
                                    };
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#etiquetaMensajeAlerta").html("No es posible establecer una conexión con el servidor.");
                                    $("#dialog-Alerta").dialog("open");
                                }
                                //height : 190,
                                //width : 865,

                                var su = jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                        .jqGrid('addRowData', cont, datarow);

                                //var sub=jQuery("#tablaProducto_1_t").jqGrid('addRowData','newRow',datarow2);
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }, "json");


            }
```

esas son las funciones

Comment: Falta el código de consultaProductos

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate que en el **Controller** si estés trayendo más de un resultado. Te sugiero que pongas el código del jsp para ver como lo estas implementando, porque tal vez sea la iteración que estas haciendo el jsp (no se si estas utilizando scriptles o jstl) y lo más seguro no sea ni el Map ni el List.

Comment: amigo Darth Vader ya agregue en la edicion el faltante del codigo que toca, aprovechando voy a instruirme con respecto a el Controller al que te refieres, de verdad que soy nuevo en esto de la programacion web y mis conocimientos son basicos, espero tu ayuda